# ClassCastException when trying to pass int value from dialog back to activity

Tags: java, android, android-dialogfragment

I've made a dialogFragment that when the OK button is clicked it sends an integer value back to a gamescreen which is the activity I think. However when I try to run the app it crashes with a ClassCastException. I've looked at online examples telling me to use an interface which I've done however I just don't know why I'm getting this exception as I have already implemented the interface into my game screen.

```
public class AddEmployeesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static interface DialogListener {
        void onNeutralClick(DialogFragment dialog, int val);
    }

    //variables
    int value = 0;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    DialogListener listener;

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        String regionName = getArguments().getString("regionName");

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        builder.setTitle("How many Employees do you want to add to " + regionName + "?");
        builder.setMessage((new Integer(value)).toString());
        builder.setPositiveButton("+", null);
        builder.setNegativeButton("---", null);
        builder.setNeutralButton("Ok", null);

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it
        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        alertDialog = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
        if(alertDialog != null)
        {
            Button positiveButton = (Button)alertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            positiveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    value++;
                    alertDialog.setMessage((new Integer(value)).toString());
                }
            });
            Button negativeButton = (Button)alertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
            negativeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(value > 0) {
                        value--;
                    }
                    alertDialog.setMessage((new Integer(value)).toString());
                }
            });
            Button neutralButton = (Button)alertDialog.getButton(Dialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL);
            neutralButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    listener.onNeutralClick(AddEmployeesDialogFragment.this, value);
                    dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public  void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            listener = (DialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                    + " must implement DialogListener");
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class SoftwarGameScreen extends GameScreen implements AddEmployeesDialogFragment.DialogListener{

//other code here...

    @Override
    public void onNeutralClick(DialogFragment dialog, int val) {
        regionValue[4] = (new Integer(val)).toString();
    }

}
```

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    PID: 2196
    java.lang.ClassCastException: MainActivity@b424f98 must implement DialogListener
        at AddEmployeesDialogFragment.onAttach(AddEmployeesDialogFragment.java:85)
        at android.app.Fragment.onAttach(Fragment.java:1478)
        at android.app.DialogFragment.onAttach(DialogFragment.java:370)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1242)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2426)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2205)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2161)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2062)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:738)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: the stack trace says your MainActivity does not implement DialogListener. your fragment is being attached to this activity, so the activity should implement it.

Comment: Ok thanks but then how would I get that information from the MainActivity back to a class in this instance my SoftwarGameScreen?

Comment: that depends on how you have everything wired together. supposing your MainActivity is holding an instance of SoftwareGameScreen you can call a method on that instance from the activity: `mySoftwareGameScreen.somethingHappened(value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to implement DialogListener interface in your MainActivity.java file.
Try writing:

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AddEmployeesDialogFragment.DialogListener{

//other code here...

    @Override
    public void onNeutralClick(DialogFragment dialog, int val) {
        regionValue[4] = (new Integer(val)).toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok thank you. Then how would I be able to get the information passed back into my SoftwarGameScreen or a class?

Comment: I have updated the answer. I think you will have to do something like this

Comment: Ok, another quick question is there a way to open the DialogFragment with a different class rather than the main activity or am I talking nonsense?

Comment: A context will be required to open the dialogFragment. So I guess that it cannot be opened from another class like that but if you pass the context of the activity to another class and use it from there then it might work.

Comment: Can you please mark this as the correct answer if it helped you? Thanks